# changing EditText

Tags: android, colors, height, gradient, android-edittext

When I change the layout_height of an EditText field in Android, the nice looking gradient becomes a hard gray line as you can see here:

[image]

Is there a way to either fix or disable this gradient?

thx
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just give it a different background, using a nine-patch presumably.  (I have noticed this too and don't like it either! :) )